# Solidity - String Template Literal

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, binance

Is it possible to write a multi line string in the solidity language on the same fashion as JavaScript allows us to do so by levering back-ticks?

I'd like to now an optimal way to save a long string in my smart contract that needs several line break without me having to escape with `\n` all over the place.

in essence this is doable in JavaScript using back-ticks
i.e.

```js
const multiLine = `
line1

line2
line3 
and so forth...
`
```

Is possible to do so in the Solidity language?

Answer (score 2):

JS lets you evaluate expressions, call functions and all kinds of stuff inside templates. sol strings won't even give you their length! So templates aren't around now.

Relevant reading:
https://hackernoon.com/working-with-strings-in-solidity-c4ff6d5f8008

I wonder how much you could develop a library for these type of features, like handlebars for .sol ...